# Automatically convert .Net null to DBNull.Value?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, dbnull

I've written a utility to handle adding values to data parameters for hand-rolling sql queries. Consumption looks like

```
utility.Add("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = {0}", myVariable, DBType.TheType);
```

or

```
utility.Add("UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = {0}", myVariable, DBType.TheType);
```

How should a null value for myVariable be handled?

1. All values should be fully trusted. The responsibility is solely upon the consumer. How would the consumer know that null would be handled anyway?
2. null can never work, so it should throw a NullArgumentException. Why go any further?
3. null should be automatically interpreted as DBNull.Value since it's the only viable solution. This is a utility, right? Make it utilizable and dry up some code!

Optional bonus question: If these arguments were made by three political candidates, what would their parties be? (Please state the home country of such parties)

Comment: Are you asking about null values returned from the query, or null values passed in as the value of `myVariable`?

Comment: I built a little sqlparameter wrapper, to handle null and other basic low-level validation so you can basically throw anyhting at it as value and it will end up as a perfeclty safe normalized data. I do translate nulls into dbnull.value

Comment: null is passed into the utility which creates a dbcommand with the command text and parameters

Comment: I don't think the bonus question is quite appropriate...

Comment: I added an additional use case to the question to further clarify. Thanks @Joe White.

Comment: -1 for involving politics in a fair scientific question.

Answer (score 1):

Rock the [Null Coalescing Op](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

In your add put another parm for the =...
    utility.Add("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn {0}{1}",
     myVariable, DBType.TheType);

When you format the string in the Add method:
    ... = String.Format(sql,myVariable is null ? " IS " : " = ", myVariable ?? "Null"

You'll probably want to expound on that a bit, e.g., stick with on parameter and toss in a temp stringbuilder; might have to use a the ?/: construct for the type, too, wherever that's being used. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Null is a valid query parameter, you don't need to convert it to DBNull to use it in a query.

Comment: Yes but you can't use Column = NULL, it needs to be IS NULL. Which the String.Format example shown does not handle.